# Calculate shortest path from start to end visiting certain node

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, shortest-path

I have the following graph:

- Graph contain **n** nodes (*p1*, *p2*, .., *pn*)
- Each node is connected to other ones with a positive cost number. Non-existing connections are marked with *infinity* cost number
- Graph is undirected (cost of (*pi*, *pj*) equals to cost (*pj*, *pi*) for any node pair)
- Graph may contain cycles, e.g. there may be a path from *pi* node that returns to that node

I need to calculate shortest path from *p1* to *pn* node visiting *pk* node (*pk* is not a start or end node). The main problem is in restriction that the solution path should not visit any node more than once. Because of that, there may be no solution at all: for example, when node **pk** have only one non-infinity connection (with **pj** node), path will have to go through **pj** node twice.

Is there any acceptable algorithm to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to suggest a modification of Winata's algorithm inspired by it - it's not great except in easy cases, but I'm beginning to suspect that this is a hard problem.

Winata suggested that we compute the shortest paths from p1 and pn to pk, and merge these to get a path from p1 to pn via pk. If this returns an answer that satisfies the extra constraint that no node is visited more than once, this solves the problem. The catch is that the solution found here may not satisfy that constraint.

I propose that we hope that the Winata answer is not too different from the correct answer and start enumerating all shortest paths from p1 to pk and from pk to pn. Given these enumerations, we can enumerate all combinations of paths from p1 to pk and pk to pn in order, and look for the first one that satisfies the extra constraint, which must be the shortest such path.

The paper at http://www.vldb.org/pvldb/vol4/p1028-golenberg.pdf describes a general method (Lawler-Murty) of enumerating solutions to problems, given a method for finding just one best solution to the problem. As an example, in Appendix A P 9 it works the problem of generating paths through a graph from source to destination in order of length.

One defect of this approach is that the enumeration methods need more and more store to keep track of stacks of cut-down versions of the problem. Another approach would be to use Winata's approach - which solves a simpler problem neglecting one of the problem constraints - to provide the lower bound in a branch and bound approach. The solution provided by Winata's approach may not be valid, but its cost is a lower bound on the cost of any valid solution, which is exactly what you need for branch and bound.

I suspect that branch and bound would in fact be a better solution, so I will try and explain this more fully. There is a general description of branch and bound at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound. It is a recursive search very similar to a depth first search, where each node corresponds to a partial solution to the problem. Here a partial solution would be a proposed central section of a path, with a few links leading up to pk, and a few links leading away from it. As you do a depth first search of the tree of partial solutions you keep track of the best solution found so far. When you recurse down to a node you try and show that no complete solution below that node can be any better than the best solution found so far, because if so you need not investigate any of the solutions formed by expanding that partial solution any further, and you can return up to the depth first search instead of recursing down below that node.

When you have a partial solution such as (Pk-1, Pk, Pk+1) you can work out the shortest path from P1 to Pk-1 and from Pk+1 to Pn. This may not be legal, but it is still a lower bound - no legal solution with (Pk-1, Pk, Pk+1) as its central section can possibly do better than the total of the paths you have worked out. So if this sum is no better than the best solution found so far you need not investigate any other partial solutions found by extending that partial solution any further. If the combination of three sections is a legal solution, visiting each node no more than once, then you have found a possible answer, and again you need not investigate any nodes below this in the tree. If the result is not a legal path, then you will have to try extending the partial solution by adding a link on the front (or the end) of it in every possible legal way, recursively looking for partial solutions below there in the tree.

If there is no solution at all, you should find that the depth first search always terminates with no way to extend each partial solution at some depth, without ever finding a full legal path. If there are solutions and you are lucky, you will quickly find a legal path with a cost so low that you can show that no other partial solution can ever be extended to beat it. - But there is no guarantee about how long the process might take - for hard problems it might take far too long to be practical.

Comment: the solution sounds pretty good. I found http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yen's_algorithm to obtain K shortest path between nodes. Is it the most effective way to enumerate combinations of paths between (_p1_, _pk_) and (_pk_, _pn_)? If you  already suggested other algorithm provided in the paper, could you explain which part of paper _Appendix A P 9_ refers for? Also, you mentioned _branch and bound_ at the end. Could you tell me more about its purpose?

Comment: I liked the very general construction used to produce top N answers, but I suspect that branch and bound would be more efficient, so I have added more about this at the end of the answer. Appendix A P 9 refers to Page 9 of the PDF paper I linked to, which starts "Appendix<newline>A. ABOUT LAWLER-MURTY's". I suspect that any enumeration of paths might have trouble where you can construct paths made of many short sections where there is a choice of links at each section, so a stretch of length N where each section is a choice of two links has 2^N possible paths.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

Since this is an undirected graph, the solution is not to difficult, namely:

- As you do the following, keep track of the parent of each node by having another array called `pathTo` which will contain `PT(k, p)`, where `k` is the current node and the parent that connects to it along the shortest path is `p`
- First run dijkstra's algorithm to get the shortest path from `p1` to all of the points connecting to `pk`. So if `pk` has 2 edges to it, you want to run this algorithm until those edges have been relaxed.
- Next you use breadth first search to find the shortest path from any of the vertices connecting to `pk`, to `pn`. This means that you will take all the vertices that `pk` has a edge to and use those as a starting point of your bfs. Note that since this is bfs, you only need to run this once and it should terminate once `pn` is reached.
- If the bfs fails to terminate before exploring the entire graph, then there is no path that goes through `pk` and ends at `pn`. Otherwise, you will trace back from `pn` to `p1` using the `pathTo` array
- ***Note that this method can be tweaked with little effort to find the shortest path from `p1` to `pn` and passing through more than one point***

Comment: if I understood your solution correctly, there can be a case of false negative failure. Suppose we have a following graph: (a,b) (b,c) (c,d), (d,i) (i,j) (j,k) (k, b), (d,e). We need to get a shortest path from **a** to **e** through **j**. Assume the shortest path from **a** to **i** is (a,b,c,d,i), from **a** to **k** is (a,b,c,d,i,j,k). In both cases, path from **i** (**k**) to **e** is blocked because we already visited **b**. Maybe if I forbid to visit **pk** node at dijkstra's algorithm time, solution will work. Could you comment my thoughts?